# Influence of division operation in cuda kernel on number of registers per thread

Tags: cuda

Im was writing a program which includes a cuda kernel. I found that if you are using`#define OPERATOR *` one thread will use 11 registers, but I you will use `#define OPERATOR /` (division operator) one thread will use 52 registers!! Whats wrong? I must
decrease register number (I dot want to set maxregcount)! How can I decrease number of registers when Im using devision operator in cuda kernel?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define GRID_SIZE 1
#define BLOCK_SIZE 1
#define OPERATOR /
__global__ void kernel(double* array){
    for (int curEl=0;curEl<BLOCK_SIZE;++curEl){
    array[curEl]=array[curEl] OPERATOR 10;
    }
}
int main(void) {
    double *devPtr=NULL,*data=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*BLOCK_SIZE);
    cudaFuncAttributes cudaFuncAttr;
    cudaFuncGetAttributes(&cudaFuncAttr,kernel);
    for (int curElem=0;curElem<BLOCK_SIZE;++curElem){
        data[curElem]=curElem;
    }
    cudaMalloc(&devPtr,sizeof(double)*BLOCK_SIZE);
    cudaMemcpy(devPtr,data,sizeof(double)*BLOCK_SIZE,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel<<<1,BLOCK_SIZE>>>(devPtr);
    printf("1 thread needs %d regs\n",cudaFuncAttr.numRegs);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you inspect the machine code generated for the kernels with `cuobjdump -dump-sass` you can see that double-precision multiplication is a built-in hardware instruction, while double-precision division is a fairly sizable called subroutine, so some expansion in register use is to be expected. The magnitude of the increase is larger than I observed in similar situations, however. Is this a release build? You can limit register usage on a per-function basis with the `__launch_bounds__` attribute. Forcing lower register use could result in spilling which can also reduce performance.

Comment: It was debug build. In realease build I have 33 regs for div, and 6 regs for mul. Im not good in engl. You said that gpu div is not an simple instruction, its a function?

Comment: Correct, double-precision division is implemented as a called subroutine (~= function) internally, as there is no direct hardware support for floating-point division in the GPU. The difference in register use you observe for the release build matches what I observed in the past.

Comment: Although one has to assume that this is not the actual background of the question, I'd like to mention the option of changing `/10` to `*0.1`.

Comment: @njuffa do you want to provide an answer?  I would upvote.

Comment: @Robert Crovella: Thanks for the endorsement. I have expanded my previous comment into an answer taking other people's comments into account as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The increase in register use when switching from a double-precision multiplication to a double-precision division in kernel computation is due to the fact that double-precision multiplication is a built-in hardware instruction, while double-precision division is a sizable called software subroutine (that is, a function call of sorts). This is easily verified by inspection of the generated machine code (SASS) with `cuobjdump --dump-sass`.

The reason that double-precision divisions (and in fact all divisions, including single-precision division and integer division) are emulated either by inline code or called subroutines is due to the fact that the GPU hardware has no direct support for division operations, in order to keep the individual computational cores ("CUDA cores") as simple and as small as possible, which ultimately leads to higher peak performance for a given size chip. It likely also improves the efficiency of the cores as measured by the GFLOPS/watt metric.

For release builds, the typical increase in register use caused by the introduction of double-precision division is around 26 registers. These additional registers are needed to store intermediate variables in the division computation, where each double-precision temporary variable requires two 32-bit registers.

As Marco13 points out in a comment above, it may be possible to manually replace division by multiplication with the reciprocal. However, this causes slight numerical differences in most cases, which is why the CUDA compiler does not apply this transformation automatically.

Generally speaking, register use can be controlled with compilation-unit granularity through the `-maxrregcount` [nvcc compiler flag](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation), or with per-function granularity using the `__launch_bounds__` [function attribute](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#launch-bounds). However, forcing lower register use by more than a few registers below the level determined by the compiler frequently leads to register spilling in the generated code, which usually has a negative impact on kernel performance.